# What is the best solution for filtering out Elasticsearch results with hate words?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to filter out docs with hate words in my ealsticsearch result. Currently we are having bool filter in every search query for the list of all words. And this results in tons of slow queries, since the list of hate words is long (So much of hatred around :( )

I was wondering what are the best practices for this spam/hate words filtering.

Here are what we are considering:

1. Pre-process : Scan the doc prior to indexing and hence mark them bad or do not index them.
   Problem :  The documents are indexed from several processes and it is difficult to force the rule on any new component some one writes.
2. Creating a percolator and running it periodically (Not sure of the best frequency and timing) to tag all documents with bad words as "badDoc" : true. Hence have a filter in all the queries.
   Problem: Not sure of the performance impact due to periodical running of percolator, secondly the same problem of discipline in all queries to exclude badDoc

Personally I would favor a pure ES solution and I am sure this is not a new problem, and hence seeking expert guidance and best practices.

Thanks and Regards
Varun

Comment: Use a percolator query to "tag" a document as "bad" _before_ it's being indexed. So, whenever you have an update or index operation, take the document, run it against the percolator, if it matches then tag it as bad and proceed with the indexing. As for the already indexed documents, you would need to run a query to find them and tag them.

Comment: Thanks the response Andrei. Would having a percolator run before every index have a performance impact?

Comment: There would be a performance impact for running the percolator query, but this will happen at indexing time. Depending on how often you index/change docs it can have a greater impact or lower. But you would move the more complex filtering part away from the day-to-day queries.

Comment: Any chance you could give these two approaches a go and test the performance implications? (the percolator and the synonym list)

Comment: I did set up a small prototype for percolator. Passing 1M documents with and without the percolator. I see a very small latency. Hence the performance, is good. However for search I have to do an additional exists in my search queries, which has same performance as the synonym solution.
Evaluating these we decided to go with an different solution. I added a new sentiment hate to existing sentiment analyser. Now docs are getting tagged as positive/negative/hate. We already have a filter for positive.. so no additional change in search. It seems to work fine. Thanks a lot for the suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using percolator to tag as bad document will also need to define a percolator which include the search criteria of all the "hate words".

One possible solution without percolator could be by defining a synonym list(if not using already) or extending the already existing synonym file in your analyzer. You can define a synonym for all the "hate words" so that they gets replaced by a single term say "badbaddocument". Now during query you can filter out the bad documents using a simple Boolean filter containing a single term.